# Node.js, Express, EJS - refresh variable to output on page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

So I have set up a Node.js server and displaying a page that shows the current CPU usage, the problem now is that I have to refresh the entire page for the variable to update, and if I just update the variable via JavaScript, it shows the right CPU usage directly after refreshing the page, but after the interval runs out, it just outputs "undefined".

Node.js Code:

```
var cpuusage = 0;
var percent = require('cpu-percent');
percent(function(err,percent){
    if(err) { }else{
        cpuusage = Math.round(percent);
    }
});
```

^ Getting the current CPU usage

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("default.ejs", {
        "cpu":cpuusage
    });
});
```

^ Assigning the value to the EJS template

default.ejs code:

```
<b>CPU</b>: <span id="showCpu"><%= cpu  %></span>% <br>
<script>
    function updateCPU(){
        document.getElementById("showCpu").innerHTML="<%= cpu %>";
    }
    setInterval("updateCPU()", 2000);
</script>
```

^ Outputting the variable value and then refreshing the span

Comment: This will not update even if the `setInterval` is fixed because it is setting a static value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling setInterval the wrong way, it expects the first argument to be a function.

```
setInterval(updateCPU, 2000);
```

By the way, if you want to update CPU usage, simply refresh your page after x seconds. Or create a cpu endpoint that return CPU usage in JSON format and hit this endpoint after x seconds to update the CPU usage without refreshing it